# How to add data to POST request using Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios

I am trying to make a POST request but am getting the following message in my chrome network tab:

> {error: "unsupported_grant_type",…} error: "unsupported_grant_type"
>   error_description: "grant_type must be client_credentials,
>   authorization_code or refresh_token"

I have been using Axios for RESTful calls and this is the POST request:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const encodedString = 'blah'//some encoded string
    const [initSpotResponse] = await Promise.all([
        axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            { data: { grant_type: 'client_credentials' } },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`,
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                }
            }
        )
    ]);
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things mentioned in other StackOverflow posts but nothing has seemed to work. Does anyone have any experience creating such a POST request? I haven't seen an axios-specific post about this issue - should I abandon axios (what should I switch to if so)?

Comment: You could try fetch, but it seems like something is wrong with your authentication. Is client_credentials supposed to be a string or did you mean to pass a variable?

Comment: @cullanrocks client_credentials is supposed to be a string, yeah

Answer (score -1):

`axios.post` accepts as second parameter the data object (`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`), serialize data with `qs` and try this, as stated [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362#issuecomment-433407468):

```js
const qs = require('querystring');


async componentDidMount() {
    const encodedString = 'blah'//some encoded string
    const [initSpotResponse] = await Promise.all([
        axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            qs.stringify({ grant_type: 'client_credentials' }),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`,
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                }
            }
        )
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I've not seen the application/x-www-form-urlencoded before. Just updated the answer

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

Comment: there's no need for `const qs = require('querystring');`